# Retrieve a CouchDB document's previous revision with revision id?

Tags: java, android, nosql, couchdb, ektorp

**How can I retrieve a couchDB document with certain revision?** I am using `Ektorp 1.2.2` API for `Android`.

I just want to pass the **docId** and **revision number** somewhere to access a particular document's revision.

I am not getting exact procedure to do that anywhere, How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are old data accessible in CouchDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730299/are-old-data-accessible-in-couchdb)

Comment: A common misconception is that there old versions of documents kept around in CouchDB. See possible duplicate link.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the revision you can load it like this:

```
String id = ...
String rev = ...
Sofa sofa = db.get(Sofa.class, id, rev);
```

This will work provided that your revision is still in the db...